# How to implement SASS in an asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, css, sass

I am searching for a solution on how to implement SASS into an asp.net project. I have searched a lot but have found no example on the web.  As far as I know some kind of JavaScript file will be needed in project in order for it to work.

Can anybody please share a sample aspx page with one or two textboxes with SASS applied to it?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, consider installing [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench), which will add the Sass file type to the new file dialog and automatically compile any Sass/SCSS/Less files to CSS. You can then just link to the generated CSS files directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sass is written in Ruby, not JavaScript.  There are a few JS compilers, but none of them are official, and none of them should *ever* be considered for use outside of development.

Outside of Ruby on Rails, there is no *integration*.  You put your source files where appropriate and use the Sass compiler to compile it and place the CSS file into your public directory.  Whether you use the command line or an application like Scout is up to you.

I personally use the command line to continuously watch my Sass files as I am working on them, and it only takes a second or 2 to compile (just slightly longer than it takes to alt-tab so I can refresh and see how it looks).

Comment: Hey cimmanon thxs for the reply but what if i want to use it in asp.net is there any way i can do it...

Comment: And?  I have used Sass with PHP, Haskell/Snap, and Scala/Lift projects.